# Как удалить предмет из корзины в интернет-магазине? java

Tags: java, android, веб-программирование, интернет-магазин

Есть корзина, есть реализация ее просмотра, есть все возможные продукты и т.д.
Корзина - ArrayList. 
Предметы в корзину добавляются когда я хочу их добавить, и отсюда вопрос - как их удалять оттуда?

```html
 public static void cart () {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                for (int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(cart.get(i));
                }
                  
                System.out.println("Enter 9 to remove products out of your cart.");
                    int s = sc.nextInt();
                    do {
                            cart.remove(s);
                        } while (s<=11);
                  
                }
```

В этом коде пытался в cart.remove(s) удалять столько раз товары, сколько напишет пользователь (s-кол-во раз). Но что-то не так. Пытался и через for, тоже не получилось.
Помогите пожалуйста кто может, буду очень благодарен.
Просьба вставлять код с ответом.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что за магическое число 11?

Answer (score 3):

В вашем коде была проблема в том, что вы удаляете `s-й` элемент списка бесконечное число раз, т.к. `s` не изменяется (условие `s <= 11` всегда `true`), соответственно цикл `do while` выполнится либо 1 раз, либо будет выполняться бесконечное число раз.

Для решения вашей проблемы можно использовать `Iterator`.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int s = sc.nextInt();

Iterator iter = list.listIterator();
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    if (iter.hasNext()) {
        iter.next();
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

В данном коде из ArrayList удалится ровно `s` элементов, которое ввел пользователь. 
Советую так же ознакомиться с 
[итераторами](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/5.10.php)